# Java RemoteWebDriver - WebElement.findElements(...) doesn't work exactly?

Tags: webdriver

I have a website to test and there is this piece of html code in it:

```
<table id="tableid">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first">
      <td>Hello World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second">
      <td>Bye World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I want to create a list of the **tr**-Tags and iterate over them with the following code:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableid']/tbody/tr"));
for(WebElement l : list){
        System.out.println(l.getAttribute("class"));
        System.out.println(l.getLocation());
        System.out.println(l.hashCode());
        System.out.println(l.findElement(By.xpath("//td")).getText());  
    }
```

These four System.out.println's are the following:
first
(32, 300)
1573
Hello World
second
(64, 600)
1574
Hello World

So the location is different, even the class attributes are different. But the getText method returns only the text from the first element. Why? Am I missing something? Doing something wrong? I can't figure it out.

EDIT/UPDATE:
This seems kind of odd. The above code does not work. If I do the following code it works fine. Any explanations?

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableid']/tbody/tr/td"));
System.out.println(list.get(0).getText());
System.out.println(list.get(1).getText());
```

Output:
 
Hello World
Bye World

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is wrong.  `//td` means "any  element anywhere in the document".  Try `l.findElement(By.xpath("td")).getText()` instead - I think you'll get the result you want.

Comment: //td means anywhere in the document, but as I do findElement of WebElement, it is in the context of the Webelement, isn't it?
It found out the class-attribute correctly, so it knows the correct element, but it can't figure out the text via getText().

Comment: No, XPath in Selenium WebDriver follows the XPath spec. To select "any descendant of the current node", you want ".//" (note the period before the double slash).